# JWT is not working as expected with Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt, authorization, middleware

I am having a hard time to get things to work as they are supposed to with `JWT` on `Node JS`.
Let me first say that my goal is (after logging in) to access the *privateRoute* route of my API.

I am always hitting a:

```
 authHeader == null
```

inside the *authenticateToken* middleware function, though I have tried many things.

So I can't pass the level of the *authenticateToken* letting me in.
As a solution to introduce what is needed inside the header and be able to get through I have thought about creating a kind of entry route to get in, but it is still not working.

Here is the relevant code.

```
app.get('/privateRoute', authenticateToken, function(req, res) {
    // Useful work to do, after logging in.
    .......
});


function authenticateToken(req, res, next) {
  // Gather the jwt access token from the request header
  const authHeader = req.headers['authorization'],
  token = authHeader && authHeader.split(' ')[1]

  if (token == null) {
    console.log('authenticateToken-401')
    return res.sendStatus(401) // There isn't any token.
  }
  // It never reaches this point !!!

  jwt.verify(token, 'myBigSecret', (err, user) => {
    console.log(err)
    if (err) {
      console.log('authenticateToken-403')
      return res.sendStatus(403)
    }
    req.user = user
  })
}


app.get('/entryRoute', function(req, res) {
  res.set('authorization', 'Bearer ' + myJWT_Token);
  res.redirect('/privateRoute');
});
```

Can someone tell me what I need to change in my code to make my (probably not so good) solution work? Or tell me a better way to do?

Below is some extra information from the browser, in case that may be useful.

In the FireFox menu, Tools, Web Developer, Web Console; Network tab. I can see the following:

For the response headers (/entryRoute):

```
Authorization : Bearer eyiwhfehihinR…CuwfihvihiL_hfgSt_J8D
Connection :keep-alive
Content-Length : 56
Content-Type : text/html; charset=utf-8
Date : Mon, 13 Apr 2020 09:46:55 GMT
Location : /privateRoute
Server : Xoibuy
Vary : Accept
Via : 1.1 vegur
X-Powered-By : Express
```

For the request headers (/privateRoute):

```
Accept : text/html,application/xhtml+xm…ml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/ *;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding : gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language : en-US,en;q=0.5
Connection : keep-alive
Host : myapp.herokuapp.com
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests : 1
User-Agent : Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel …) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0
```

Comment: Can you share the request information from Network tab of Developer tools or value of request object?

Comment: I just added some information I could find in the browser, hoping this is what you need. Please take a look at the post again, towards the end.

Comment: I can see that what I do about Authorization is not passed to privateRoute. This may just show that my way of doing is just wrong.

Comment: You must pass Authorization header to your http request to get it passed through your AuthenticateToken middleware

Comment: try accessing it like: ```req.header('Authorization')```.  Also you'll need to call ```next()``` once verified it to get it to go to your function

Comment: @Abhishek Jain. Yes I must pass Authorization header to my http request. And this is exactly what I don't know how to do. If you know please let me know.

Comment: @Daniel Swiegers. This is what I have been trying for a while. And req.header('Authorization') is always null. If you understand why, please tell me.

Comment: @Michel Can you share how are you accessing the '/privateRoute'? I mean which libarary axios, fetch or XMLHttpRequest?

Comment: Nothing of that, this is just a route as any other route in my Node.js app as you see it in my post. The problem is that I don't pass through authenticateToken. My other route "app.get('/entryRoute'," was only intended as a work around to solve the problem but it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My reputation is still low so I couldn't post a comment. I think there's nothing wrong with your code. I think you do the Http request the wrong way as the authorization header is not passed to the request. I don't know what language you are using on the frontend but I'll assume it's JavaScript. You could do it this way.

```
const consumeApi() = async () => {
   const response = await fetch('https://example.domain/endpoint', {
      method: 'POST' // could be any other methods (GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, etc)
      headers: {
         'Authorization': 'Token some_token_value'
      }
   });

   // Response status other than 200
   if (response.status !== 200) return alert('Something wrong happened.'); 

   // Response status 200
   // do someting ...
}
```

Using the above code, you should be able to add authorization header to your Http request. Hope this helps.

-- EDIT
You can try to create a new HTML file. Let's say example.html which  looks like this

```
// example.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script>
   const consumeApi() = async () => {
      const response = await fetch('https://example.domain/endpoint', {
         method: 'POST' // could be any other methods (GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, etc)
         headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Token some_token_value'
         }
      });

      // Response status other than 200
      if (response.status !== 200) return alert('Something wrong happened.'); 

      // Response status 200
      // do someting ...
   }

   // call the function directly after loading the HTML page
   consumeApi().then();
</script>
</html>
```

Then try to open the example.html file via a web browser and it should be calling your api directly. This way, you should be able to make a request to your node.js server with an Authorization header. Hope this helps

Comment: Your suggestion looks promising and you assume right. I am indeed using JavaScript. I am not sure at this point, where I should insert your code; but I'll experiment and see.

Comment: I'll edit my answer so you can try out the code immediately

Comment: I have tried to work from your code in example.html. Though I have made some progress, it seems something is missing. Because I can never see https://example.domain/endpoint appear in the browser, which should be what happens at the end.

Comment: @ Leng Long. Everything I can see or check in the logs indicates that it all happens as expected, but for some unknown reason nothing shows up in the browser.

Comment: If the backend or node.js side is working perfectly, then I suppose there's no problem. The html code I provided above is empty and is only for testing purposes (in this case testing your node.js api).

Comment: I accepted your answer. Not that it directly and immediately solved my problem but it put me on the right track. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem, glad it helps